# Prevent css from affecting another component Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-router

I have a project, first it's just a normal SPA, but then I have to merge another Vue project to it, it leads to css conflicts...

Now I have a router like this:

```
{
  path: '/admin',
  name: 'Home',
  component: MainContainer,
  redirect: '/admin/posts/list',
  children: .....
},
{
  path: '/',
  component: Container,
  children: .....
}
```

It means I have 2 systems in 1 Vue app, but using different CSS. My attemp is use scoped css for the main component - here is `MainContainer` and `Container`. But using scoped style make the style not affect to these child component. Is there anyway for children of `MainContainer` only use `style1.css` and `Container` only use `style2.css`? If I delete scoped, the style of `style1.css` also affect `Container` and so on

I can check the vue router and reload the page to clean the old css when page change from `MainContainer` => `Container` or reverse, but it seems not to be the right way to do.

Comment: You might try adding prefixes for the separate stylesheets using something like https://github.com/RadValentin/postcss-prefix-selector.

Comment: Is that mean I have to add a new class to every DOM element and use postCss to fix the css file?

Comment: It depends on your html structure, you may be able to use a single wrapper element with the prefix class and it would cascade to all the wrapped elements.